# PHP Column Sum Result MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(Veldspar) FROM hauled WHERE miningrun=2 AND hauler=1";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$veldtotal = mysql_fetch_array($result);

printf("Results:  %s<br>", $veldtotal);
printf("Length of array: %s<br>", count($veldtotal));
printf("Array into Int: %s<br>", (int)$veldtotal);
```

Why does the first printf return a blank variable?
All I want to be able to do is to get the sum of the query, and pass it to a variable to be displayed on the screen.  Can anyone help with this?

Comment: if this code is new, please avoid mysql_* functions, prefer PDO and mysqli features.

Comment: The rest of the project is not new.  I am adding a new feature to an existing opensource project, and I cannot use other things than what is there in the rest of the project.

Answer (score 2):

That would be because `mysql_fetch_array` returns an array. You can get to the result using `$veldtotal[0]`.

Comment: I edited the code as you said, and the return I received when running was the following:<br> Results:

Answer (score 0):

Use this or var_dump() to know what ur getting in `$veldtotal`

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($veldtotal);
```

Comment: but wouldn't you get a single value from the `SUM()` in SQL?, I mean the statement, as it is written will only come up with a single row with the SUM of `veldspar`

Comment: I only want a single row answer as after I pull the value, I will have to do math on it and then store it in a different array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the calculated sum in your query, you should name it:

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(Veldspar) AS total FROM hauled WHERE miningrun = 2 AND hauler = 1";
```

And read it:

```
printf("Results:  %s<br>", $veldtotal['total']);
printf("Length of array: %s<br>", count($veldtotal));
printf("Array into Int: %s<br>", (int)$veldtotal);
```

You can also read it by using $veldtotal[0]

Comment: Tried this solution, and it still returned a blank answer.  When I add the debug condition in as another user suggested the array had no value in it, but when I do the query on the sql server it returns a value.

Comment: Try reading the values in $veldtotal by using <pre><?php print_r($veldtotal); ?></pre> after the query. If the sum is shown, then try changing your printf-statement by an echo.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(Veldspar) FROM hauled WHERE miningrun=2 AND hauler=1";

$veldtotal = mysql_result(mysql_query($query), 0, 0);

printf("Results:  %s<br>", $veldtotal);
printf("Length of array: %s<br>", count($veldtotal));
printf("Array into Int: %s<br>", (int)$veldtotal);
```

Besides, what does `Length of array` mean?

Comment: I wanted to make sure I was getting an array of some length.